# Bash Date formatting

Tags: bash, date, concatenation

I"m having problems formatting my dates using bash. I"m looking for a simple script that can create a range that looks like '2014-10-05_2014-09-30_Thisformat/'

```
 enddate= $(date +%F) #store in a variable so that it can be read later
 startdate= $(date +%F -d "5 days ago") #store in a variable so it can be read later

 range= $startdate"_"$enddate"_"Thisformat/"
 echo $range
```

Thanks for taking a look

Comment: It looks like you have an extra space on the right side of the equals sign. Spaces aren't allowed on either side in assignments in bash. And your quotes are wrong. Try `range="${startdate}_${enddate}_Thisformat/"`

Comment: haha that was it! Thanks a lot (can't believe it was a stupid error like that"

Comment: @ooga: Quotes are okay, as long as there are no spaces or special characters in the strings. Quoteless should work as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct answer was

```
enddate=$(date +%F)
startdate=$(date +%F -d "5 days ago")
range=${enddate}"_"${startdate}"_Thisfile/" 
echo $range
```

The problem was an extra space in front of the equals. Thanks ooga for the help!